# Autocomplete using typeahead.js (JSON string from database) - how to add additional var?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, typeahead

Im trying to make an autocomplete selector (typeahead.js) with JSON.

Now i got working code - i can start typing and i got autocomplete but i got only "Name Surname - Company Name" displayed.

What should i do if i would like to get an additional info like ID of that company from database? How can i pass that var through JSON and somehow pass to html form?

Working code:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInput">User</label>  
    <input type="text" id="user" name="user" size="30" class="user form-control typeahead" placeholder="User">
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
        return $.get('helpers/szukaj_uzytkownika.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Server-side:

```
<?php
include ('../db.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE company_name LIKE '%".$_GET['query']."%' OR person_name LIKE '%".$_GET['query']."%' OR person_surname LIKE '%".$_GET['query']."%'LIMIT 10"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$json = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $json[] = $row['person_name']." ".$row['person_surname']." - ".$row['company_name'];
}
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

I will appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Server-side:

```
<?php
    include ('../db.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE company_name LIKE '%".$_GET['query']."%' OR person_name LIKE '%".$_GET['query']."%' OR person_surname LIKE    '%".$_GET['query']."%'LIMIT 10"; 
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $json = [];
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $json['name'] = $row['person_name']." ".$row['person_surname']." - ".$row['company_name'];
        $json['id] = $row['id'];
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    source:  function (query, process) {
    return $.get('helpers/szukaj_uzytkownika.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            var id = data.id;
            return process(data.name);
        });
    }
});
```

---